# Find the range of $f(x)= \frac{x}{(1+x^2)}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

$f(x) = \frac{x}{(1+x^2)}$

I need to find the range of function.

My method-

Let $f(x)=y$

Then $x²y-x+y=0$

$$x=1\pm\frac{\sqrt{(1-4y²)}}{2y}$$

For $x$ to be real ,

$1-4y^2\ge0$ **and** $y\neq 0$

$(2y+1)(2y-1)\ge0$ **and** $y\neq0$

Hence $y \in [-1/2,1/2] -\{0\}$

So far so good.

But if I put $0$ in the function,

Then $f(0)= 0/1+0 =0$

While my solution says that $y$ cannot be zero.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Please use *MathJax*.  Your"equations" such as x/1-x^2 and (x/1-x^2) make no sense!!!

Comment: I apologise I've just started to learn MathJax

Comment: The equation should be $x^2y+x-y=0$. While using that discriminant is non-negative, it is assumed that $y\ne 0$.

Comment: You forgot to split cases into $ y \neq 0 $ (use discriminant) and $ y = 0 $ (use something else)

Comment: $(0,0)$ satisfies the equation though

Comment: [MathJax tutorial](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a second degree equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$ in order to use the formula 
$$
x = \frac{{ - b \pm \sqrt {b^2  - 4ac} }}
{{2a}}
$$
it must be $a \neq 0$. As $a=0$ your equation turn to be $bx+c=0$ which get of course 
$x=-c/b$ (as long as $b\neq 0$). In your case, you have that, if $y=0$ your equation
is $0x^2+x+0=0$ so $x=0$.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

This can be equal to $0$.

You solved this problem for $y\neq0$.

Now, easy to see that $y=0$ holds.

I like the following way.

Let $x>0.$

Thus, by AM-GM
$$\frac{x}{x^2+1}\leq\frac{x}{2\sqrt{x^2\cdot1}}=\frac{1}{2}.$$
The equality occurs fpr $x=1$.

Also, for $x<0$ by AM-GM again we obtain:
$$\frac{x}{x^2+1}\geq\frac{x}{2\sqrt{x^2\cdot1}}=\frac{x}{2|x|}=\frac{x}{2(-x)}=-\frac{1}{2}.$$
The equality occurs for $x=-1$.

Now, let $x=0$.

We obtain a value $y=0$.

Thus, since $f$ is a continuous function, we got the following range:
$$\left[-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right]$$

Comment: But in the expression for x , since y is in the denominator , it cannot be zero right? I understand that y=0 holds , but why does my answer show otherwise?

Comment: @ijustwannacry Your reasoning is true for $x\neq0$. Now you need to consider another case: $x=0$, which gives a value $y=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer ...

In your efforts to describe the solution set of the statement $$y = x/(1+x^2),$$ you manipulated algebraically, and arrived at the statement $$x = (1 + \sqrt{1-4y^2})/2y \qquad \text{or} \qquad x = (1 + \sqrt{1-4y^2})/2y,$$ and focused your attention on describing its solution set, which appeared to be the same as that of the first statement. It is *almost* the same - when you manipulated algebraically you altered the original solution set by dropping the point $(0,0)$.

Comment: And which step led to the altering of solution?

Comment: It is true that $y = x/(1+x^2)$ if and only if $yx^2 - x + y = 0$, so the solution set did not change by that point. You then applied the quadratic formula to the latter polynomial, so my hunch is that the solution set changed when you manipulated the coefficients $y,-1,y$ of this polynomial by those manipulations used to discover the quadratic formula.

Comment: I got it. Thank you so much or it'd have bugged me all night long!